# Stack Top Method not writing to .txt file

Tags: java

I have a program that reads in a grocery list from a .txt file.  I am creating a test driver utilizing methods that are in my Stack class and the results are printed in an outputlist.txt file instead of the console.  The Stack class includes push() pop() and top() methods.  My push and pop methods work fine, but when I call my top method, it will not print to the outputlist.txt file.  I've tested to check if the method will print to console and that works fine.  This is the error message I get when trying to write to the file using the top method: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: LLNode cannot be cast to GroceryItems.  I have included the TestDriver class.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    public class TestDriver{

       public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{    
         FileWriter out = null;
         Stack<GroceryItems> item = new Stack<GroceryItems>("Grocery List");

          try{
                out = new FileWriter("outputlist.txt", true);                        
                File listFile = new File("grocerylist.txt");
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(listFile);      
                String name;
                int quantity;
                double price;



                while(scan.hasNextLine()){
                   name = scan.next();  
                   quantity = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
                   price = Double.parseDouble(scan.next());
                   item.push(new GroceryItems(name, quantity, price));                      
                }
                out.write(item.toString());

                   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                      item.pop(); 
                   }
                   out.write("New List after 5 pops:\n");
                   out.write("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n");
                   out.write(item.toString() + "\n");
                   out.write("Top test:\n");
                   out.write("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n");
                   out.write(item.top().toString()); //This is where I am getting the error message.              



          }catch (IOException ioe){
             System.out.println(ioe.toString());
          }
          catch (StackOverflowException soe){
             out.write("Push attempted on a full stack.");
          }
          catch (StackUnderflowException sue){
             out.write("Pop attempted on an empty Stack.");

          }
          out.close(); 
           System.out.println(item.top()); //This prints to console fine.       

       }
    public class Stack<T> implements UnboundedStackInterface<T>{

       private LinkedList<T> list;  //top of the stack.


       public Stack(String name){
          list = new LinkedList<T>(name);
       }
       public void push(T element){
            list.insert(element);

       }
       public void pop(){            
         list.remove();        
       }    
       public T top()throws StackUnderflowException{
           if(isEmpty())
             throw new StackUnderflowException("Top attempted on empty stack.");
           else        
          return (T)list.getLast();                            
       }
       public boolean isEmpty(){
          return (list == null);   
       }
        public boolean isFull(){
            return false;
        }
       public String toString(){            
            return list.toString();
       }   
    }


    public class LinkedList<T>{


    private String name;
    private LLNode<T> first;
    private LLNode<T> last;
    private int size = 0;


    public LinkedList(String name){
        first = null;
        last = null;        
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void insert(T element){
        LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T>(element);
        newNode.setLink(null);
      if(first == null)
         first = newNode;         
      if (last != null)
         last.setLink(newNode);      
        last = newNode;
        size++;
    }    
    public int size(){
        return size;            
    }
    public void remove()throws StackUnderflowException{
        LLNode<T> current;      
        current = first;    
        if (size == 0)
            throw new StackUnderflowException("Pop attempted on an empty stack.");
        else if (size == 1){
            last = null;
            first = null;
            size = 0;
        }
        else{
            while(current.getLink() != last){                              
                current = current.getLink();                

          }
            current.setLink(null);         
            last = current;     
            size--;
        }                   


    }
   public LLNode<T> getLast(){
      return last;   

   }        
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String listString = "List: " + name + "\n\n";
        LLNode<T> node;
        node = first;

        while(node != null){
            listString = listString + node.getInfo() + "\n";
            node = node.getLink();
        }
        return listString;

    }
}
```

Comment: This program works well for me when I use default java Stack class with .peek() instead of .top(). Have you made your own Stack implementation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in `Stack<T>` you define `list` as `LinkedList<T>`, where `LinkedList<T>` is the **class that you have implemented latter**. Your `Stack#top` is doing `LinkedList#getLast` and `getLast` returns `last` which is of type `LLNode<T>`, where in your case is `LLNode<GroceryItems>`. Since `LLNode` is not of type `GroceryItems` - you are getting that exception.

You have not included the implementation of `LLNode`, but if there are method in `LLNode<T>` class that returns `T` - then you need to call it.

so changes needs to go in this line: `out.write(item.top().toString()); //This is where I am getting the error message.`

Answer (score 0):

Your `getLast()` returns a `LLNode<T>` So when you do this

```
return (T)list.getLast();
```

Your trying to cast `T` to `LLNode<T>, which is wrong because`T`is not a subtype nor supertype of`LLNode`.  This is why you are getting a`ClassCastException`.

Try this, in your `top()` methoed.

```
return (NodeLL<T>)list.getLast();
```